# custom hash table implementation - memory error while mapping strings to integers

Tags: c++, hashmap, hashtable

I am practicing the implementation of the hash map in C++. My goal is to ultimately map words to a pair of integers that correspond to their line and column in a text file. I took the hash map implementation from [here](https://medium.com/@aozturk/simple-hash-map-hash-table-implementation-in-c-931965904250) and build upon that. The code works fine when I pass words with only one letter. However, when I have a word with more than one letter, the code compiles on Visual Studio, but at runtime throughs read access violation at this line:

```
HashNode<K, V> *entry = table[hashValue];
```

(within the insert member function). I thought there might be some tweaks that I should consider when using strings in a temple structure that I might not be aware of; however, I couldn't really find itout after hours of searching the web. Any ideas on how to fix this is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#define TABLE_SIZE 1028

template <typename K, typename V>
class HashNode {
public:
    HashNode(const K &key, const V &value) :
        key(key), value(value), next(NULL) {
    }

    K getKey() const {
        return key;
    }

    V getValue() const {
        return value;
    }

    void setValue(V value) {
        HashNode::value = value;
    }

    HashNode *getNext() const {
        return next;
    }

    void setNext(HashNode *next) {
        HashNode::next = next;
    }

private:
    // key-value pair
    K key;
    V value;
    // next bucket with the same key
    HashNode *next;
};

template <typename K, typename V, typename F = KeyHash<K>>
class HashMap {
public:
    HashMap() {
        // construct zero initialized hash table of size
        table = new HashNode<K, V> * [TABLE_SIZE]();
    }

    ~HashMap() {
        // destroy all buckets one by one
        for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; ++i) {
            HashNode<K, V> *entry = table[i];
            while (entry != NULL) {
                HashNode<K, V> *prev = entry;
                entry = entry->getNext();
                delete prev;
            }
            table[i] = NULL;
        }
        // destroy the hash table
        delete[] table;
    }

    void get(const K &key, vector<V> &value) {
        unsigned long hashValue = hashFunc(key);
        HashNode<K, V> *entry = table[hashValue];

        while (entry != NULL) {
            if (entry->getKey() == key) {
                value.push_back(entry->getValue());
                //return true;
            }
            entry = entry->getNext();
        }
        //return false;
    }

    void insert(const K &key, const V &value) {
        unsigned long hashValue = hashFunc(key);
        HashNode<K, V> *prev = NULL;
        HashNode<K, V> *entry = table[hashValue];

        while (entry != NULL && entry->getKey() == key) {
            prev = entry;
            entry = entry->getNext();
        }

        if (entry == NULL) {
            entry = new HashNode<K, V>(key, value);
            if (prev == NULL) {
                // insert as first bucket
                table[hashValue] = entry;
            }
            else {
                prev->setNext(entry);
            }
        }
        else {
            // just update the value
            entry->setValue(value);
        }
    }

    void remove(const K &key) {
        unsigned long hashValue = hashFunc(key);
        HashNode<K, V> *prev = NULL;
        HashNode<K, V> *entry = table[hashValue];

        while (entry != NULL && entry->getKey() != key) {
            prev = entry;
            entry = entry->getNext();
        }

        if (entry == NULL) {
            // key not found
            return;
        }
        else {
            if (prev == NULL) {
                // remove first bucket of the list
                table[hashValue] = entry->getNext();
            }
            else {
                prev->setNext(entry->getNext());
            }
            delete entry;
        }
    }

private:
    // hash table
    HashNode<K, V> **table;
    F hashFunc;
};


int main()
{
    struct MyKeyHash
    {
        unsigned long operator()(const string & s) const
        {
            int hash = 7;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
            {
                hash = hash * 31 + s[i];
            }
            return hash;
        }
    };

    HashMap<string, tuple<int, int>, MyKeyHash> hmap;
    hmap.insert("BB", make_pair(3, 3));
    hmap.insert("A", make_pair(1, 2));
    hmap.insert("A", make_pair(4, 2));

    vector<tuple<int, int>> value;
    hmap.get("B", value);
    for (auto it : value)
    {
        cout << get<0>(it) << ", " << get<1>(it) << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: *when I have a word with more than one letter, the code compiles on Visual Studio, but at runtime through a memory violation error.* -- You should know that compiling with no error has no bearing on whether there are logical bugs or not.

Comment: Thanks for the great point. Made some edits. The violation error is actually read access violation. Details are now given in the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned long hashValue = hashFunc(key);
//...
table[hashValue]
```

The `hashValue` is returned from the function

```
unsigned long operator()(const string & s) const
{
    int hash = 7;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        hash = hash * 31 + s[i];
    }
    return hash;
}
```

which can return arbitrarily large values (in the range of `int`). But `table` is an array of length `TABLE_SIZE` (1028). If the output happens to be larger than that, you are accessing it out-of-bounds.

The way the function is written, this is more likely to happen for longer input strings.

You probably meant

```
unsigned long hashValue = hashFunc(key)%TABLE_SIZE;
```

Also note that your hash function overflows, causing undefined behavior (because you are using signed integers), if the string is long enough. You should be using `unsigned long` instead of `int`, matching the return type and being unsigned.

Comment: I found the hash function somewhere in here. There was a question about best way defininig hash functions for strings. Any ideas on hash functions?

Comment: Actually never mind. `31` is prime and doesn't appear as prime factor of `TABLE_SIZE`, so that might be ok. I would need to check in detail. Still, you need to change `int` to `unsigned` or `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an important step for using the hash map.  You've calculated the hash, and you have a table to store things in, but you can't use the hash directly as an index into the table.  It needs to be reduced modulo the size of the table to keep the subscript valid.

In this case, after computing the hash (calling the `hashFunc` member), you need to include

```
hashValue = hashValue % TABLE_SIZE;
```

You'll want to eventually add code to determine when you need to grow the size of the hash table, which will require TABLE_SIZE to be a member of the HashMap.